# React component type variance and assignability

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Context**

I have two components. Props of one component inherit from the props of another one.

```
declare namespace Props {
  interface Fruit {
    price: number;
  }

  interface Banana extends Fruit {
    curvature: number;
  }
}

declare const Fruit: React.FC<Props.Fruit>;
declare const Banana: React.FC<Props.Banana>;
```

The facts are:

- `React.FC` is defined by React as just a function of props.
- We know functions types are covariant in their return type and contravariant in their argument type. [Source](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance)

**Problem**

Now, when trying to assign one to another in TypeScript `3.4.0-rc` we get:

```
/**
 * ✅ Compile-time error. Function arguments are contravariant.
 */
const fruit: typeof Fruit = Banana;

/**
 * ✅ No error. Function arguments are contravariant.
 */
const banana: typeof Banana = Fruit;

/**
 * ✅ No errors as expected.
 */
const one: React.ReactComponentElement<typeof Fruit> = <Fruit price={3} />;

/**
 * ⁉️ No errors (but expected one). Now it's covariant.
 */
const two: React.ReactComponentElement<typeof Fruit> = <Banana price={3} curvature={15} />

/**
 * ⁉️ No errors (but expected one). Now it's contravariant.
 */
const three: React.ReactComponentElement<typeof Banana> = <Fruit price={3} />

/**
 * ✅ No errors as expected.
 */
const four: React.ReactComponentElement<typeof Banana> = <Banana price={3} curvature={15} />
```

**Question**

Why do `two` and `three` not cause an error?

Comment: I think the root question is what is the type of `<Banana price={3} curvature={15} />`. from what I can tell the type is always `JSX.Element` which is `React.ReactElement<any, any>`. So while the type to represent a typed jsx element exists it seems unused by the compiler, I think the compiler just returns `JSX.Element` without bothering to do anything else..

Comment: And the related GitHub ticket: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14729

Comment: Thank you @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. I was wondering if that was desired behavior — this proves that there's more to this story.

Comment: I think it's the implemented bahavior. The issue I referenced does sugest the team would be open to improving this.

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding JSX and using React.createElement solves this issue.

```
declare namespace Props {
  interface Fruit {
    price: number;
  }

  interface Banana extends Fruit {
    curvature: number;
  }
}

declare const Fruit: React.FC<Props.Fruit>;
declare const Banana: React.FC<Props.Banana>;

// ✅ 
const one: React.ReactComponentElement<typeof Fruit> = React.createElement(
  Fruit,
  { price: 1000 }
);

// ✅
const two: React.ReactComponentElement<typeof Banana> = React.createElement(
  Banana,
  { price: 1000, curvature: 12 }
);

/**
 * ✅ Compile-time error.
 * Type 'FunctionComponentElement<Banana>' is not assignable to type
 * 'ReactComponentElement<FunctionComponent<Fruit>, Pick<PropsWithChildren<Fruit>, "price" | "children">>'.
 * ...
 * fruits.tsx(10, 5): 'curvature' is declared here.
 */
const three: React.ReactComponentElement<typeof Fruit> = React.createElement(
  Banana
);

/**
 * ✅ Compile-time error.
 * Type 'FunctionComponentElement<Fruit>' is not assignable to type
 * 'ReactComponentElement<FunctionComponent<Banana>,
 * ...
 * Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible. 
 */
const four: React.ReactComponentElement<typeof Banana> = React.createElement(
  Fruit,
  { price: 12 }
);
```

But it creates another one -- [we lose autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAbPv.png) on props in VSCode.

Comment: can you give any guidance on current best practices with typing JSX? I'd assume we want to keep using jsx, but... maybe not?

Comment: @DevinGRhode

Firstly, I need to notice that JSX types changed a bit since this questions was asked (libraries can export [`namespace JSX`](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/master/packages/react/types/jsx-namespace.d.ts)

And to answer your question: I don't want to discourage anyone from using JSX. It's one of the best DSLs for UI composition, and I use it on daily basis.
Frankly, I never needed `React.ReactComponentElement<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but this could be useful for some approach. (A Work In Progress that I don't want to get lost in my `git stash`)

```
// "React Create Element"
type RCE<
  HTMLNodeType extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement
> = React.DetailedReactHTMLElement<
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLNodeType>,
  HTMLNodeType
>
type RCE_string<
  HTMLNodeType extends 'div' ? HTMLDivElement : HTMLElement
> = React.DetailedReactHTMLElement<
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLNodeType>,
  HTMLNodeType
>
const t: RCE<HTMLDivElement> = <div />
const d: RCE<'div'> = <div />

const elementTypeMap ={
    Anchor: HTMLAnchorElement,
    Area: HTMLAreaElement,
    Audio: HTMLAudioElement,
    Base: HTMLBaseElement,
    Body: HTMLBodyElement,
    BR: HTMLBRElement,
    Button: HTMLButtonElement,
    Canvas: HTMLCanvasElement,
    Data: HTMLDataElement,
    DataList: HTMLDataListElement,
    Dialog: HTMLDialogElement,
    Div: HTMLDivElement,
    DList: HTMLDListElement,
    Embed: HTMLEmbedElement,
    FieldSet: HTMLFieldSetElement,
    Form: HTMLFormElement,
    Heading: HTMLHeadingElement,
    Head: HTMLHeadElement,
    HR: HTMLHRElement,
    Html: HTMLHtmlElement,
    IFrame: HTMLIFrameElement,
    Image: HTMLImageElement,
    Input: HTMLInputElement,
    Mod: HTMLModElement,
    Label: HTMLLabelElement,
    Legend: HTMLLegendElement,
    LI: HTMLLIElement,
    Link: HTMLLinkElement,
    Map: HTMLMapElement,
    Meta: HTMLMetaElement,
    Object: HTMLObjectElement,
    OList: HTMLOListElement,
    OptGroup: HTMLOptGroupElement,
    Option: HTMLOptionElement,
    Paragraph: HTMLParagraphElement,
    Param: HTMLParamElement,
    Pre: HTMLPreElement,
    Progress: HTMLProgressElement,
    Quote: HTMLQuoteElement,
    Slot: HTMLSlotElement,
    Script: HTMLScriptElement,
    Select: HTMLSelectElement,
    Source: HTMLSourceElement,
    Span: HTMLSpanElement,
    Style: HTMLStyleElement,
    Table: HTMLTableElement,
    TableCol: HTMLTableColElement,
    TableDataCell: HTMLTableDataCellElement,
    TableHeaderCell: HTMLTableHeaderCellElement,
    TableRow: HTMLTableRowElement,
    TableSection: HTMLTableSectionElement,
    Template: HTMLTemplateElement,
    TextArea: HTMLTextAreaElement,
    Title: HTMLTitleElement,
    Track: HTMLTrackElement,
    UList: HTMLUListElement,
    Video: HTMLVideoElement,
    WebView: HTMLWebViewElement
}
```